# standard error of the estimated slope coefficient

Tags: regression, variance, regression-coefficients, standard-error

Consider the fitted values from a simple linear regression model with intercept: yˆ = 7 + 4x.

Assume that the total number of observations is n = 20. In addition, the explained sum of squares is SSE = 10 and the residual sum of squares is SSR = 30. Under the classical Gauss-Markov assumptions:

What is the standard error of the estimated slope coefficient?

It asks to calculate s.d. of coefficient of x. However, based on theequation Var (β1) =σ2 (X′X)−1 , we can not get the value of Var (β1) as the values of X are not given in the question. Just wondering if anyone could provide some insights and procedures for the solutions. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the first question you posted to address the closure reason. If you disagree with the closure of that question, please do comment why. However, please do not post a question again after it has been closed.